# http://localhost/ appears before path

Tags: php, html

In the beginning of the PHP file, I am defining the ROOT as

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

It works when i use something like

```
require_once(ROOT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'config/bootstrap.php');
```

However, when using the same `ROOT` while including the css within the HTML seems to create a problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PrePress &middot; Login</title>
        <link type="text/css" href=<?php echo ROOT . DS . 'views/type.css ?> rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

On tracing the path of the CSS file, the full path starts with `http://localhost:8888/Users/...`. Here I simply want my path to start from `/Users/` which will be able to find my css file, whereas having the `localhost` changes the path and the file can no longer be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/views/type.css"; ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Hi. This does not work for me. It does the same thing again by appending the localhost

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use that format in an href. Just use

```
<link type="text/css" href="views/type.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To give a relative address, which makes the code much more transportable

Comment: But this will work only if the file is at the same directory level as the views folder.

Comment: True, however `href="/views/type.css"` will always be relative to the site root.

Comment: All correct, but I dont know the questioners directory structure. Do you?

Comment: @MarkParnell will be correct, however in order to get that functionality I will need to define something like `define ('BASE', 'sitename/dir');`

Comment: Why, you dont need the sitename it is implied. Remember its the browser that will try and resolve this not your PHP. Using the above or `<link type="text/css" href="/views/type.css" rel="stylesheet">` will cause whatever site this code runs on to add the `http://` and `mysite.com` in from of whatever you put in here.

Comment: That is correct, however, when running it on localhost, i have several other projects, and each project starts with `http://localhost/project_name`. Hence, the site name will be required.

Comment: If you have multiple projects then you should be using Virtual Hosts. That way each project gets its own DocumentRoot and things work as if they were hosted on there own server. Here is a howto http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,121115,121310#msg-121310

Answer (score -1):

use

```
<?php $path = glob($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/views/type.css"); ?>

<link type="text/css" href="<?php $path; ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the base url and that should link to your project folder. If you are not using a framework then I suggest you do.

Once you have set your base url you can call css and javascript from your header and footer respectively, and include the header and footer on your pages i.e `$this->load->view('includes/header);` and `$this->load->view('includes/footer);`

This is how you would typically call your scripts, I have only mentioned the href property within the tags as you should know the rest.

```
<script href="<?php echo base_url('link to your script goes here');?>" />

<link href="<?php echo base_url('link to your sheet goes here);?> />
```